# system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror the media set has 2 families but only 1 are provided -- Need only Partial data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore, recovery, data-recovery

media set has 2 families but only 1 are provided. I understand that restore in not possible ALTHOUGH, I only need a portion of the data. Is there any way to retrieve anything from this .bak file?  MS SQL Server 2016 Standard.  I am certain that the db part that I do have has the VAST majority of the data.  God, PLEASE say it's possible!

Did a back, not realizing I ended up with only part of the db. DB was deleted, accidentally.  Their is, about, 1000 man hours of data I really need to get out of the bak file. Running a file recovery app now but it's iffy.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with SQL Compare from Idera, it can use backup files to do comparisons and it might be able to work with a partial (I have never tried it).

Doctor google came up with this 
https://download.cnet.com/SQL-BAK-Reader/3000-2065_4-75608958.html bit looks like it just does header stuff.

You may have to use a sector editor to read the file and see if you can make heads or tails out of it.

It might also be worth calling Microsoft support.

But in general, no I have not heard of a approach to this.

Comment: Thanks Henry, that gave me a a good start.  I have an 11gb db and the missing ldf file is 60kb. Anyone know how to recreate this file or...something?